# WireBox: Map a Java class and immeriately call a method

Tags: coldfusion, railo, coldbox, wirebox, fusionreactor

Is there an easy way to just map the result of  `createObject("java", "com.intergral.fusionreactor.api.FRAPI").getInstance()` to a WireBox alias?

Mapping a regular class is easy, but in this case I'd like to keep things clean and just map a singleton of the returned instance in one step instead of having to use a boilerplate provider as a go-between.

I obviously know about the regular `toJava()` and `toDSL("javaloader:...")` basics, but it's the point about getting straight to the `getInstance()` method of the class that has me wondering.

I'm sure there's an easier way to do this, but right now I just can't see the woods for all the trees.

Environment details: ColdBox Platform Bundle 3.8.1, Railo 4.2

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd suggest asking this on the ColdBox Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/coldbox

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to try here first, because the response times are usually better.